# URL for compose Facebook Message (new layout)

Tags: facebook, url, message

I've use following URL to send message with prefill text.
http://www.facebook.com/messages/[user]?msg_prefill=[message]
ex. http://www.facebook.com/messages/facebook?msg_prefill=hello

But msg_prefill parameter seem to be depreciated on new Facebook Message layout.
http://mashable.com/2012/08/22/facebook-revamps-messages-to-look-more-like-email/

Does anyone know how to add prefill message for new layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't send message with prefill text. But I've found another way to send link using Send Dialog.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

ex. 1
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&to=zuck&name=Hello&link=http://www.google.com/&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/

However this may not working for some people (including me) as using some domains in "link" parameter cause error as this bug.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284149695026014?browse=search_509788e98cb627971133933

ex. 2
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=People+Argue+Just+to+Win&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCili.Pica%2Fapp_469715143040257&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fresponse

Also, Send Dialog links can't use on iPhone apps, Android apps and mobile version of facebook.

ex. 3
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&to=zuck&name=Hello&link=http://www.google.com/&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?